# No sound from Ardour or Hydrogen using JACK on new install of Ubuntu Studio 20 on 2013 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook, macbook-pro, ubuntu-studio, jack, ardour

On a 2013 Macbook Pro (Retina) with a new installation of Ubuntu Studio 20, no sound is being produced from Ardour (digital audio workstation) or Hydrogen (drums/sequencer) while JACK audio connection kit is running.  If I stop JACK and manually set Hydrogen's preferences to use ALSA, it does produce sound, but JACK is necessary for my workflow so I can't work around it.

Answer (score 2):

The initial settings for JACK on first install of Ubuntu Studio 20 on a 2013 Macbook don't work for the laptop's built-in audio.  A few changes need to be made to the defaults.

1. Start QjackCtl from the upper-left system menu, under Audio Production -> Audio Utilities.
2. Hit the "Setup" button on the middle-right.
3. You may want to use a different Preset Name so you don't lose any settings you currently have.
4. **Set the Interface to hw:PCH,0 (i.e. the CS4208 Analog option).**
5. Click the "Advanced" tab.
6. **To the right of the Channels I/O label, there are two dropdowns.  Set *both* of these to 2.**
7. Click OK, then either Stop/Start QjackCtl or restart it completely.
8. Make sure QjackCtl is in the "Started" state.
9. Start Ardour.  Under the Window -> Audio / MIDI Setup menu, make sure the Audio System indicates it's using JACK.
10. In Hydrogen, under Options -> Preferences, under the "Audio System" tab, make sure it is either automatically or explicitly using JACK.

You can verify that it works in Ardour by clicking the Metronome button, which is the second from the left (beneath the Session menu), then hitting the play button.  You should hear some sounds.

Other audio programs (e.g. Audacity) might also need to have their preferences set to use JACK while QjackCtl is running.

Comment: Two unrelated but useful adjustments to the default OS install on an MBP are 1) changing the resolution via the upper-left system menu -> Settings -> Display so the text isn't tiny on the Retina screen, and 2) choosing an option like Default-hdpi or Default-xhdpi under Settings -> Window Manager to get window borders that aren't too thin to grab and resize